# concatenate with leading zeros for months - not a valid month error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, concatenation

I want to concatenate string with year in oracle. The string is month.
Query is

```
 select to_date('11'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1,'MMYYYY') from dual;
```

This query wrks fine however if the string is '01' or anything starting with zero i am getting not a valid month error.

```
select to_date('04'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1,'MMYYYY') from dual;
select to_date('05'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1,'MMYYYY') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run it without the `to_date(..., ...)` wrapper:

```
select '04'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 from dual;

'04'||EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE)-1
--------------------------------
                           42019
```

Do you see the problem? (Note that the result is a number, not even a string.)

Concatenation is performed before you subtract 1. You get the string '042020' first, and then you subtract 1; the string is converted to number, and you get the result 42019. When you apply `TO_DATE()` this is converted back to string, and the first thing Oracle will choke on is the `42` for month.

Use parentheses around the arithmetic operation to force the subtraction to be performed first, and it will work:

```
select to_date('04'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1), 'MMYYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('04'||(EXTR
-------------------
2019-04-01 00:00:00
```